# Different holding/maintenance/503 pages for different themes - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, frontend, maintenance

I have a multistore site (6 stores) that use 3 different themes, my question is:

**How do I set a different maintenance/holding/503 page for different themes?**

I can't find anything mentioning this so I'm starting to think you can only have one holding page across all stores/themes. My only idea so far is to try and check the themes inside `503.phtml` and alter the markup depending on the theme.

Comment: This answer is for M1, but should work in the same ay in M2 ... we have different themes in different languages with this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/186868/46249

Answer (score 0):

The theme of the error page is stored to the pub/errors/design.xml:

```
<skin>default</skin>
```

There is no dynamic resolution of the correct theme for the error page. It seems like writing your own resolver is the only option.

Comment: Thanks, I can change a holding page but not a different one across different stores