# Multistore Maintenance Mode Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, maintenance

We currently have a multistore Magento 2 set up, we have a custom maintenance page set up using /pub/errors/default/503.phtml, this shows fine when the sites go into maintenance mode, we however want to show a translated message on each page rather than it just being in English. Is this possible?

Comment: please see my below answer. if you want me to work. i will do this. thanks

Comment: Updated my answer - it only needs some rewrite rules.

Comment: Dit it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, just quick code check ... and it seems it works the same way as in Magento 1.

> By default Magento doesn't support translation out-of-box for error pages, and requires some customizations to allow for such features. So technically there is no **proper** way to do such.
>
> Since the full stack is NOT initialized during error generation, normal translation functionality `$this->__('foobar');` won't work in the templates.

From [Translate Maintenance mode per website in multiwebsite-multidomain setup](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88988/translate-maintenance-mode-per-website-in-multiwebsite-multidomain-setup)

Maybe you try to adopt the ideas from there ...

Edit:

> Magento uses maintenance mode to **disable bootstrapping**; for example, while you’re maintaining, upgrading, or reconfiguring your site.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html

Soo its not possible oob ..

---

### Update:

Found another way for translated maintenance page:

1. In you .htaccess add an rewrite rule that appends a `skin` parameter to your URL. Eg.

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^french.example.com$
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/var/.maintenance.flag -f
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)skin=french(&|$) [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?skin=french[L]
   ```
2. Copy `pub/errors/default` to `pub/errors/french`
3. Change/translate template files to your needs

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible. You need to add translation files. First thing you need to do is that in your template file write message like this 
echo __('Your message').

Then you need to add translation csv files in a new module.
Create a new module

lets say it is LanguagePack

Create registration.php inside module

```
    <?php


\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'yourcompanyname_LanguagePack',
    __DIR__
);
```

crate module.xml file inside etc folder. 
LanguagePack/etc/module.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="yourcompanyname_LanguagePack" setup_version="1.0.0">

    </module>
</config>
```

Then Createfolder i18n inside your module and place all translations files in this folder. for example for french it will be line fr_FR.csv and add french translation against english text.

Comment: Have you tested it for error pages?

Comment: you need to change location of your maintenance file.

Comment: It does not work.