# How can I display a custom maintenance message on Magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, error, apache2, maintenance

I have to update several modules of Magento, also deactivate others and during that the frontend will not be available.

How can I make a simple personalized message? Would you touch on some Magento or Apache directory?

And how can I make a separate message page for every language?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multistore Maintenance Mode Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250689/multistore-maintenance-mode-magento-2)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this You need to update below file

> pub/errors/default/503.phtml

and design accordingly

but best practice to override this into custom error page for this follow below steps.

Go into the **pub/errors**

Create a copy of the **local.xml.sample** and rename it as **local.xml**
Edit the  with your custom name. Ex – **customerrorpage**

```
<skin>customerrorpage</skin>
```

http://prntscr.com/mr8kgy

Next create a copy of the **“default”** folder and rename it with your skin name. Ex – **customerrorpage**

Locate the **503.phtml** inside the newly created folder and add your custom code. Add the styles inside css/styles.css and relevant images under images folder.

http://prntscr.com/mr8l75

For particular language (store view wise) you need to do using .htaccess

In you .htaccess add an rewrite rule that appends a skin parameter to your URL. Eg.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^french.example.com$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/var/.maintenance.flag -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)skin=french(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?skin=french[L]
```

Copy pub/errors/default to pub/errors/french

Change/translate template files to your needs

Reference [Multistore Maintenance Mode Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250689/multistore-maintenance-mode-magento-2/250696#250696)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks!!can i do a error page for every language?

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Maybe it appears in DevDocs soon ... https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/3393 :) +1 for (my) answer :P

Answer (score 7):

you can go to pub directory and find below path:

> pub/errors/default/503.phtml

and quick edit on the `503.phtml` file and edit this lines also css add here

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!can i do a error page for every language?

Comment: Done! And i updated my question :D

Comment: my pleasure.. :)

Comment: Sorry, now done!

Comment: Hellooooo! Can you tell me how can i do a multi language error page? For every store on magento @Rakesh Donga