# Magento2 - Maintenance page

Tags: magento2.3, php-7.2

I want to show the custom page while running the Magento commands like (upgrade, di: compile, deploy).

How to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: please check it here and file available https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/263827/68695

Answer (score 0):

Magento seamlessly provides maintenance mode, which allows/denies access from particular IP addresses.

To enable maintenance mode for all clients:

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

To disable maintenance mode for all clients:

```
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

To enable maintenance mode for all visitors except some IPs (like: 192.0.2.10 and 192.0.2.11):

```
magento maintenance:enable --ip=192.0.2.10 --ip=192.0.2.11
```

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html

This will display default Magento's maintenance page.

If you want to customize the way of maintenance, you can use custom made extensions like:

- https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-better-maintenance
- https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-maintenance-page.html