# Custom under maintenance page when bin/magento maintenance:enable

Tags: magento2, maintenance

I have a local magento 2 shop running and I would like to set up an under maintenance page when maintenance mode is enabled. Right now when enable maintenance mode it only shows:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled. 

Exception #0 (Exception): Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled. 
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:40]
</pre>
```

How can I set up a custom page? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

Here is the documentation on how to achieve this.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/maint-mode.html

Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, but it does not seem to work. I have found another suggestion: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263825/how-can-i-display-a-custom-maintenance-message-on-magento-2-2-4  but this also does not seem to work.

Comment: What version of Magento are you using?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.3.4

Comment: I have found the problem. I am using docker for my local magento shop and the custom files weren't copied into the container. After copying them it worked.